# How to prevent react page refresh when file changes in src folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a typescript react project with a simple JSON file as a database. The website has a form that when submitted sends an API request using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to a local server that makes changes to the file.

My problem is that whenever the JSON file is changed (Manually or Via code) the site refreshes. How can I prevent this?

The component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import FormControl from "react-bootstrap/FormControl";
import api from '../../backend/Services/api'


const Workout = (props: any) => {
    const [day, setDay] = useState(props.workout.day);
    const [time, setTime] = useState(props.workout.time);
    const [type, setType] = useState(props.workout.type);

    const handleSave = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(
            `Updating workout (${props.workout.id})- day: ${day}, time: ${time}, type: ${type} `
        );
        // updateJson(props.workout.id, day, time, type);
        console.log('Before wait')
        // let response = await api.patch(`/modify/${props.workout.id}/${day}/${time}/${type}/`)

        api.patch(`/modify/${props.workout.id}/${day}/${time}/${type}/`)
        .then(response => {console.log('Response: ' + response.data.msg)})
        .catch(e => {console.log(e)})   
    };


    return (
        <tr>
            <td colSpan={4}>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <Button
                                    variant="primary"
                                    type="button"
                                    onClick={handleSave}
                                >
                                    Save
                                </Button>
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <Form.Group>
                                    <FormControl
                                        onChange={(e: any) => {
                                            setDay(e.target.value);
                                        }}
                                        as="select"
                                        defaultValue={day}
                                    >
                                        <option>Sunday</option>
                                        <option>Monday</option>                                        
                                    </FormControl>
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <Form.Group>
                                    <FormControl
                                        onChange={(e: any) => {
                                            setTime(e.target.value);
                                        }}
                                        as="select"
                                        defaultValue={time}
                                    >
                                        <option>07:00</option>
                                        <option>08:00</option>                                        
                                    </FormControl>
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <Form.Group>
                                    <FormControl
                                        onChange={(e: any) => {
                                            setType(e.target.value);
                                        }}
                                        as="select"
                                        defaultValue={type}
                                    >
                                        <option>Endurance</option>
                                        <option>Strength</option>                                        
                                    </FormControl>
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
};

export default Workout
```

The api file containing the axios instance:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `/workoutApi`,
    proxy: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 4000
    }
})

export default api
```

My package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "backend": "node_modules/.bin/ts-node --project tsconfig.api.json src/backend/Server/server.ts"
  }
```

To run I use `npm run backend` then `npm run start`

Shortly:
JSON file in src is changed -> The page refreshes
How can I change the JSON file without the page refreshing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide content from `package.json`'s `scripts` section and `webpack.config`. It's all because of [`watch` feature](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) that makes development easier but should be configured to avoid reloading for changes in specific files

Comment: @skyboyer I added the `package.json`'s `scripts` but my project doesn't have a `weback.config`

Comment: You should move that json file outside your src directory and it will stop refreshing your page but in reality this is a thing that only affects your devel environment and won't happen in your build.

Comment: @StavrosAngelis I tried to move the JSON file outside the src directory but it gave me this error: `Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../user.json which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.` And, the fact that the page refreshes makes all the forms reset. I have multiple forms so I would like for this to work in my dev environment.

Comment: looks like CRA does not allow configuring that out-of-box. [Ejecting will allow](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject) to configure that but probably it makes more sense to host `user.json` on your backend side and load it through XHR call instead of bundling it.

Comment: Since you already have an API in place to update the json file, instead of directly importing it you can do a get and load it's values. So to sum up, you should move the json file outside of your src directory. Then when loading your app add an api call to load the data from the json file.

Comment: @StavrosAngelis I cant access the file if it's outside the src directory. And i'm not importing it with `import` I'm using fs.readFileSync()

Comment: You write in your description "The has a form that when submitted sends an API request using axios to a local server that makes changes to the file". I assume this is a node server running on the side. If that is the case then the server is a separate project than your react front-end project and should be kept separately. Now in that server app you can create another api endpoint that when called will run the function that reads the file and return the data in a json form for your front-end to consume and load.

Comment: @StavrosAngelis I understand what you're saying but shouldn't my backend code be included in the same project? Most of the project is about the backend, the website is a simple UI for using the backend.

Comment: Not really, you should keep it separate. Maybe have an upper level directory for your entire project but under that you should split front-end and back-end.